# Как использовать Spring Boot совместно с созданой мною аннотецией (@interface)?

Tags: java, spring-boot, аннотации, configuration

Знаю, что такое аннотации и как они работают,  и как работает Spring Boot, но никак не могу понять - 
Если я напишу собственную аннотацию, как мне определить обработчик этой аннотации и как он будет взаимодействовать с остальным приложением написанном на Spring Boot, а так же как такой функционал конфигурировать?
Как написанные аннотации работают в контексте spring boot?

**Есть такой вариант решения данного вопроса**

Написанная мною аннотация

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface About {

  Class expected() default Object.class;
  int value();
}
```

Класс реализующий PostProcessor который работает с аннотированными полями используя рефлексию

```
@Component
public class AboutCustomPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {


private Log logger;

public AboutCustomPostProcessor(Log logger) {
    this.logger = logger;
}

@Override
public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
    return bean;
}

@Override
public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
    if (bean.getClass().getName().equals(Answer.class.getName())) {
        for (Field field : bean.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            if (field.isAnnotationPresent(About.class)) {
                logger.info("ВЫЗВАН BEAN: ");
                logger.info(bean.getClass().getName());
                logger.info("поле: ");
                logger.info(field.getName());
                int ab = field.getAnnotation(About.class).value();
                field.setAccessible(true);
                try {
                    field.set(bean, ab);
                    logger.info(field.get(bean).toString());
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    }

    return bean;
 }
}
```

Но я не знаю, правильный ли это подход.

Comment: А в чем собственно вопрос? Код работает? Если да то все ОК. Если нет, то что конкретно не работает?

Comment: Код работает, я просто хочу понять - какой правильный подход, то что я сдесь указал правильно с точки зрения проектирования, или есть более лучший вариант?

Comment: Лучший вариант - использовать spring aop для взаимодействия с кастомными аннотациями, либо использовать композитные аннотации, но можно и через bean пост процессор. Смотря, какой юз кейс у вас.

Comment: В вашем случае - один раз печатается название поля, название класса при создании контекста. В этом таком случае бин пост процессор подходит. А вот если вы хотите печатать это при каждом обращении к бину, в таком случае - spring aop будет лучшим решением.

Comment: @aleshka-batman спасибо, за помощь, это я и хотел понять, какой способ ещё есть и когда его можно использовать. Можете оформить как ответ на вопрос